# Regex in python - Parse complex data groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

How can I parse the following data using regex expressions:

```
Test data 1
  Measurement 1     X            :      -0.100  Y :      2.300
  Something   1                  :       0.00
  Stuff       1                  :       0.00
  Needed      1     X            :      -0.800  Y :      5.300

Test data 2
  Measurement 1     X            :      -0.600  Y :      4.300
  Something   1                  :       0.30
  Stuff       1                  :      -0.20
  Extra       1                  :      -0.800
```

I want to extract the Measurement 1 data (X and Y values) and the Needed 1 data (X and Y values) from Test data 1

I also want to extract the Measurement 1 data (X and Y values) and the Extra 1 data from Test data 2

The measurements have the same names just under different table names.

```
for line in data:
  if "Test data 1" in line
    match = re.match (r"   Measurement  1   X          :     ([\-\d\.]+)    Y :       ([\-\d\.]+)\s*$", line)
    if match:
       X_table1 = match.group(1)
       Y_table1 = match.group(2)
  if "Test data 2" in line
     match = re.match (r"   Measurement  1   X          :     ([\-\d\.]+)    Y :       ([\-\d\.]+)\s*$", line)
    if match:
       X_table2 = match.group(1)
       Y_table2 = match.group(2)
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please include your data in a formatted text block, not as an image.

Comment: Does your data contain more than two "Test Data", or always exactly two? And can either contain `Needed` or `Extra`, or both, or possibly neither? (and if both, always in the same order?)

Comment: Only two "Test data", but the name "Test data" is generic just for example purposes.  And "Test data 1" always contains "Needed", never "Extra" and "Test data 2" always contains "Extra", never "Needed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're processing your data one line at a time but the X and Y values are on different lines than the segment headers. Because of that, your code needs to remember which segment it currently processes (i.e. a simple parser). Also, you can reuse a generic pattern to extract the X and Y values.

```py
data1 = data2 = False
xy_pattern = r'X\s+:\s+([\-\d\.]+)\s+Y\s+:\s+([\-\d\.]+)'

for line in data:
    # set state
    if "Test data 1" in line:
        data1 = True
        continue
    elif "Test data 2" in line:
        data1 = False
        data2 = True
        continue

    # extract data
    if data1 and 'Measurement' in line:
        matches = re.findall(xy_pattern, line)
        if matches:
            X_table1, Y_table1 = matches[0]
    elif data2 and 'Measurement' in line:
        matches = re.findall(xy_pattern, line)
        if matches:
            X_table2, Y_table2 = matches[0]
```

In the same way, you can check for the `Extra` line. Note however that your matches are still strings so you might want to convert them to floats, depending on what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
    l = re.split(r'\n{2}', f.read())            # split the file into two blocks
    for i in l:
        if 'Needed' in i:
            m = re.search(r'Measurement.+X\s*:\s*(-?[\d.]+)\s+Y\s*:\s*(-?[\d.]+)', i)
            X_measure_table1, Y_measure_table1 = m.groups()
            m = re.search(r'Needed.+X\s*:\s*(-?[\d.]+)\s+Y\s*:\s*(-?[\d.]+)', i)
            X_needed_table1, Y_needed_table1 = m.groups()
        elif 'Extra' in i:
            m = re.search(r'Measurement.+X\s*:\s*(-?[\d.]+)\s+Y\s*:\s*(-?[\d.]+)', i)
            X_measure_table2, Y_measure_table2 = m.groups()
            m = re.search(r'Extra.+:\s*(-?[\d.]+)', i)
            X_extra_table2, = m.groups()
```